# Why verify the IP address and browser of a logged in user?

Tags: php, security

I'm working my way through a security assignment where we're hardening a PHP application against security issues. One of the things that was suggested we do is 'verify the user's IP address and browser'.

I can see a few reasons why you might want to verify an IP address: you could check to see if the user was using their 'home' ip address, and ask them additional security questions if they were using an uncommon IP.

Is that the basic gist of it, though? Is there anything else you'd want to do with their IP and browser information?

Comment: A common ip verification process is to check whether it's not from an uncommon geographic location. For example a user which is logging in from the US, cannot be logging in from South-Africa within 5 minutes...  You could also check against RIPE databases to account for IP-spoofing and you could have systems in place which need an admin to verify an IP before it can be used to login from...

Comment: One caveat is that users on public wifi, mobile devices and those accessing your site through proxies can often appear to be from wildly different locations, even within a short timeframe. You also have the problem of multiple users from one IP (public wifi, work network, etc), which makes tying cookies and session info to a specific IP a bad idea. The user agent string isn't reliable (it can be changed easily), but it's good for feature detection and identification of (honest) bots and crawlers. I'd pay more attention to an IP/UA that changes between requests.

Comment: This question appears off topic and would be better suited over at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea behind the verification of user's IP and Browser is related to Session hijacking attacks. Following threat can be counted as most common cases

- Attacker can do Man In The Middle (MITM) against your client and can get session key (cookie) . Which means that attacker can use this cookie value and hack client's account
- You application may be vulnerable against Cross-Site Scripting attacks. That mean attacker can control client's browser content and execute any Javascript codes. Which mean that attacker can get session keys (cookie) clients.

You need to protect your clients even if they lost their cookie values. Best approach to do that is checking out client's IP.

Further info [1] : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack

Further info [2] : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet